# ASP.NET MVC - Streaming video from controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video, streaming

I have the following working code for video streaming, created from various examples and research I've done. It works perfectly fine on chrome, but I can't seem to get it working on Safari and mobile browsers. I specifically want to stream the content, rather that download the full file before play.

I've read that mobile browsers don't like auto play, but the issue I'm experiencing doesn't seem to be that. I think I might be missing something. I've tried changing the code up in different ways. My current line of thinking is that it could be the way Safari and/or mobile browsers interpret the request payload, but even after setting the content-type to video/mp4, I have no luck.

Error I get from SAFARI (13.1.2) on my MacBook Air when I try to play() the HTML video element.

> NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.

> Status: rejected

> Stack: play@[native code]↵global code↵evaluateWithScopeExtension@[native code]↵↵_wrapCall

Also tried it on the same MacBook, using Chrome. Works fine.

[Possible Theories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = Roles._SYS_ADMIN)]
public async Task FetchVideo(int videoID)
{
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[4096];
    int length;
    long dataToRead;

    try
    {
        Video video = new Video();
        video.Get(videoID);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(video.Content))
        {
            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = memoryStream.Length;

            Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=video.mp4");
            Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";

            int startbyte = 0;

            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = await memoryStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    await Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[buffer.Length];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - buffer.Length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Response.Close();
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#play-video-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var promptUrl = '/Admin/Bundle/FetchVideo?videoID=' + value.Video.ID;
  var videoPlayer = $('#play-video-modal #video-player');
  videoPlayer.attr({
     'src': promptUrl, 
     'type': 'video/mp4',
     'autoplay': 'autoplay',
     'loop': 'loop',
     'muted': 'muted',
     'controls': 'controls',
     'playsinline': 'playsinline' 
  });

  // Set video description
  videoPlayer.text(data.Description);
});
```

HTML markup:

```
<!-- start: play video modall -->
<div class="modal fade" id="play-video-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-uppercase" id="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row p-0 m-0">
                    <div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0">
                        <div id="video-player-container" class="section d-flex justify-content-center embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video id="video-player" class="embed-responsive-item" style="background-color: black;" autoplay playsinline muted>
                                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="modal-loader" class="text-center pt-4" style="display: none;">
                <div class="spinner-grow text-primary" role="status">
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="decline-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end: play video modal -->
```

I've tied a few things. The only thing I've had working as a stable solution on all browsers, was to download the entire file then set source, using a Ajax request. Best streaming result that I got working is the one I provided in code here, but it only works on Chrome.

After some further testing, I've been able to play/stream the videos on a Samsung Galaxy S20 phone. So it seems to be a issue specifically linked to MacOS Safari and AppleOS browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the request network response in SAFARI, after enabling developer tools. I saw that there is a initial request with a header of Range 0-1.

I found a related answers '[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)' that mentions the initial byte range request of 0-1 bytes (2 bytes), mentioned by @KajMagnus and @pedrociarlini.
Further research landed me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996396/safari-9-0-can-not-play-mp4-video-on-the-storage-server).

> First, the Safari Web Browser requests the content, and if it's an
> audio or video file it opens it's media player. The media player then
> requests the first 2 bytes of the content, to ensure that the
> Webserver supports byte-range requests. Then, if it supports them, the
> iPhone's media player requests the rest of the content by byte-ranges
> and plays it.

I then decided to comb through my code and make sure everything is perfectly in order for SAFARI's very precise needs. I found that the section of my code that reads the 'RANGE' header was a bit off and needed some tuning.

After all the changes, I was left with the below working code. It works in all browsers (the ones I've tested), such as Chrome, SAFARAI and well as the mobile versions of those two.

ACTION:

```
public async Task FetchVideo(int videoID)
{
    try
    {
        Video video = new Video();
        video.Get(videoID);

        long fileSize = video.Content.Length;
        long totalByte = fileSize - 1;
        long startByte = 0;
        long endByte = totalByte;
        int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024; // 24KB buffer size

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["X-Playback-Session-Id"]))
            Response.AddHeader("X-Playback-Session-Id", Request.Headers["X-Playback-Session-Id"]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["Range"]))
        {
            //Range: <unit>=<range-start>
            string range = Request.Headers["Range"].Replace("bytes=", "");
            string[] rangeParts = range.Split('-');
            startByte = long.Parse(rangeParts[0]);
            if (rangeParts.Length > 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rangeParts[1]))
                endByte = long.Parse(rangeParts[1]);
        }

        // recalculate after range has been interpreted
        int bytesToRead = Math.Min((int)(endByte - startByte + 1), bufferSize);

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", $"bytes {startByte}-{endByte}/{fileSize}");
        Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
        Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Name", video.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Version", "1.0");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Vendor", "XMP");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Size", bytesToRead.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytesToRead.ToString());
     
        Response.StatusCode = 206;
        Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(video.Content))
        {
            memoryStream.Seek(startByte, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            long bytesRemaining = bytesToRead;

            while (bytesRemaining > 0)
            {
                int bytesRead = await memoryStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;

                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    await Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    await Response.OutputStream.FlushAsync();
                    bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
                }
                else
                {
                    break; // Client disconnected
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<video id="video-player" class="embed-responsive-item" style="background-color: black;" controls muted autoplay loop playsinline>
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

JS/JQUERY

```
var promptUrl = '/Store/Shop/FetchVideo?videoID=' + value.Video.ID;
var videoPlayer = $('#play-video-modal #video-player');
videoPlayer.attr({
    'src': promptUrl,
    'type': 'video/mp4',
    'autoplay': 'autoplay',
    'loop': 'loop',
    'muted': 'muted',
    'controls': 'controls',
    'playsinline': 'playsinline'
});

// Set video description
videoPlayer.text(data.Description);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble streaming videos on your website, especially in Safari and some mobile browsers, you can follow these steps to ensure it works across all platforms:

1. Check Video Format: Make sure your video files are in the MP4
   format, which is widely supported.
2. HTTPS: Ensure your website is using HTTPS. Some browsers require a
   secure connection for video autoplay to work.
3. Add a Poster Image: Safari may need an initial image before playing
   the video. Add a poster image to your video element. eg:

```html
<video poster="image.jpg" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

4. Seekable Video: Make sure your video is seekable, which means users
   can jump to different parts of the video. Set the controls attribute
   in your video element.
5. Use 'playsinline': For mobile Safari, include the playsinline
   attribute in your video element, just like you did in your code.
6. Testing on Real Devices: Test your website on real mobile devices,
   not just emulated ones. Real devices can behave differently.
7. Update Safari: Ensure your Safari browser is up to date with the
   latest version.
8. Check for Server Issues: Ensure your server is not causing problems
   with video streaming. Check server logs for errors.

Following these steps should help you stream videos on Safari and mobile browsers.